# Find sub sequence with predefined sum

Tags: python, arrays, list, recursion

Hey stackoverflow community,

I have the following problem. I have predefined list of numbers. For example

```
input_list = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, -6, -6, -4, 3, 3, -8]
```

What I'm no to try to accomplish is to find a subset with a given outcome_list size and outcome_list sum, so that every outcome_list has the requested size and the requested sum.

for example:

```
>> get_all_sum_lists(input_list, size=3, sum=0)
[[2, 2, -4], [-6, 3, 3], ...]
>> get_all_sum_lists(input_list, size=2, sum=-1)
[[3, -4]]
>> get_all_sum_lists(input_list, size=1, sum=0)
[]
```

First idea: The straight forward solution is to try every combinations, but this scales terrible. This would end up in O(n^size)
Second Idea: The problem has some interesting properties like:

```
get_all_sum_lists(input_list, size=4, sum=3) in get_all_sum_lists(input_list, size=2, sum=1).extend(get_all_sum_lists(input_list, size=2, sum=2))
```

so I thought something like recursion or induction could work. But my idea to build up everything from size=1 to the requested size leads to the same complexity as above O(n^size)

Somebody have a solution for this with lesser complexity?

Comment: what about using `itertools`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With itertools combinations you can have the sublists of the desired length, and you can then filter them by sum. I am not sure about the performance though, let me know if it is decent or not:

```
import itertools

def f(list_, length_, sum_):
    return list(set([i for i in itertools.combinations(list_, length_) if sum(i)==sum_]))
```

Examples for your input_list:

```
f(input_list, 3, 0)

[(-6, 3, 3), (2, 2, -4), (1, -4, 3)]

f(input_list, 5, 10)

[(2, 2, 2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1, 3, 3)]
```

Comment: The performance is still bad. For my small use case it seems to be enough, so I accepted this elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you should try to do is, divide the input array into two sub-arrays, containing negative and positive integers. In every possible case, your solution will have at least one element from each array. You should sort both of the sub-arrays, positive in ascending and negative in descending order. I would start by picking the first elements of the sub-arrays and then incrementing.
Depending on the requested size you should decide how many elements(from each sub-array) will you pick at first.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 additional ideas:

1. If you are running multiple queries to the same data, may I suggest **sorting list items** prior processing. It will take some additional time, but will cut the time for all following queries. If you don’t care about order `if (-4, 3) = (3, -4)`, it will also compress the results.

Example:

```
list_input = [-6, -4, 3, 3, -8, -4]
get_all_sum_lists(input_list, size=2, sum=-1)
```

will output:

```
unsorted = [(3, -4), (-4, 3)]
sorted = [(-4, 3)]
```

2. After sorting, you can also reduce the number of repeated items to maximum the `size` variable input. This will reduce the search space and therefore the processing time:

Example:

```
size = 2
input_list = [-3, -3, -3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]   ->   cut_input_list = [-3, -3, 2, 2, 3]
# from 9 to 5 items

size = 3
input_list = [-3, -3, -3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]   ->   cut_input_list = [-3, -3, -3, 2, 2, 2, 3]
# from 9 to 7 items
```